# How to properly implement sumifs in excel?

Tags: excel, sumifs

I have a table as follows which has year month combinations in rows and columns in sheet "grid".

---

---

1. 

```html
year    year    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2019    2020    2020
year    year-mm 2019-1  2019-2  2019-3  2019-4  2019-5  2019-6  2019-7  2019-8  2019-9  2019-10 2019-11 2019-12 2020-1  2020-2
2019    2019-1  3   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-2  4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-5  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-6  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-7  0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
2019    2019-8  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   1   1   1   1
2019    2019-9  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
2019    2019-10 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   1   0   1   0
2019    2019-11 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1
2019    2019-12 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2020    2020-1  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   3
2020    2020-2  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6
2020    2020-3  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2020    2020-4  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

[image]

Considering the above table as row data, I am trying to create a separate table which only filter for a given year(using drop down in cell D5). The expected output should look like as below but getting #Value Error.
[image]

Comment: Please post your input data as text table so that we can copy paste.

Comment: added it but seems not in the correct format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `FILTER()` function. Try-

```
=FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:P18,Sheet1!A2:A18=D5),Sheet1!B1:P1=D5)
```

[image]

If you want to include side column containing `yyyy-m` then use `VSTACK()` and `HSTACK()` function like-

```
=LET(x,FILTER(FILTER(Sheet1!B2:P18,Sheet1!A2:A18=D5),Sheet1!B1:P1=D5),y,FILTER(Sheet1!B3:B18,Sheet1!A3:A18=D5),z,FILTER(Sheet1!C2:P2,Sheet1!C1:P1=D5),HSTACK(VSTACK("Year-Month",y),VSTACK(z,x)))
```

[image]

Comment: I used `FILTER(FILTER(grid!C3:AX50,grid!B3:B300='final result'!F6),grid!C2:ZZ2='final result'!G5)` and still getting #VALUE

Comment: What is your excel version? Can you confirm that, your version of excel support `FILTER()` function?

Comment: I am using excel on onedrive, office 16

Comment: Office 16 doesn't have `FILTER()`. But excel online version have it.